# Advanced Wget usage

Tags: bash, wget

I have a list of about 200 servers which contain links to individual files, for this question, let's just pretend they're .txt files. I need to download every file, however some servers only have the compressed version, and not the original and some servers have both, the compression used is bzip2.

That means a server could have the following files;

```
foo.txt.bz2
bar.txt
bar.txt.bz2
```

I've told wget to only download .txt files and .txt.bz2 files and I'm using no-clobber to prevent the same file being downloaded from each server. However, once a compressed file is downloaded, it is decompressed; the original is kept, the bz2 files is not. This means that wget is downloading the same bz2 files from every single server because it doesn't have a compressed version locally.

How do I tell wget to *not* download .bz2 files when it already has the decompressed version (eg, don't download foo.txt.bz2 if foo.txt already exists).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would chain the `wget` commands this way:

```
wget http://example.com foo.txt || wget http://example.com/foo.txt.bz2 && bzip -d foo.txt.bz2
```

The `bzip -d` command will decompress the archive but only if the wget is successful.